# Koala - get number of likes for a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm facing an issue using Koala 1.7.0rc1 and the new Facebook graph api. I'm trying to retrieve number of likes for a post using this request `[object_id]/likes?summary=1`. This query works in Facebook Graph Explorer but I cannot access 'summary' using Koala :

```
likes = graph.get_object("5718732097_10151698726822098", summary: 1){|data| data['likes']}
# OR
likes = graph.get_object("5718732097_10151698726822098/likes?summary=1")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do:

`graph.get_object(your_post_id, :fields => "likes.summary(true)")`

The api documentation that Facebook gave is kind of misleading here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

It says `summary = 1` which should be `summary = true` in rails

Comment: awesome. 

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to get the summary data from the raw response in Koala, like so:

```
likes = graph.get_object("5718732097_10151698726822098/likes?summary=1").
              raw_response["summary"]["total_count"]
```